# Western Digital Passport Unlock locks again when it sleeps

Tags: external-hard-drive, passwords

My Western Digital Passport is password protected and whenever the drive goes back to sleep (or after a unknown period of time) the drive is locked again; as in I need to enter the password again to unlock it.

Is there a way to prevent it from going to sleep or expiring the unlock so quickly?

Comment: No. You're trying to defeat the purpose of the lock. You could look at the myriad ways to keep the drive spinning, but that will reduce the life expectancy of the drive, which is also not recommended.

Comment: The purpose of the lock is not to lock the drive again because it's gone to sleep while I'm in the middle of playing a movie. Yes that does happen, I suspect it is because the video player buffers the drive's content causing it automatically goes to sleep. This means that whenever I'm in the middle of a full screen movie, I must have to retype my password again in order to play it. Could you point me to programs that allow me to keep the drive spinning?

Comment: The drive has no idea you're watching a movie. It asks for a password when it spins down because that's how it's designed. I'd sooner use TrueCrypt's whole drive encryption, which only asks for a password when you mount the drive.

Comment: Yes I realise that, the way to solve it could be to have some ability to increase the time of which OSX tells the drive to go to sleep because it is idle or perhaps have a program to write random bytes to it in order to keep it alive. My question still stands, are there any programs out there to prevent it from going to sleep (ergo lock itself again)?

Comment: I'd write a script and add an entry in crontab. It doesn't have to be complicated.